# Date conversion - Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, date-conversion

I've a table with dates fields.

The into these fields are written in the following format

```
21-DEC-16 11.39.22.000000000 AM
```

Can anyone help me in converting these values to another format, for example epoch?

```
1482320362
```

Thanks in advance

PS: Oracle version is "Oracle12c"

Comment: How is the column defined exactly? Date, timestamp, varchar2?

Comment: the column is defined varchar2